# EF6 many-to-many, WillCascadeOnDelete and multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-design

In EF6 CodeFirst, I want to model a many-to-many relationship with navigation properties.

The classes:

```
public class Event
{
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}

public class Notification
{
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

class EventConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Event>
{
    public EventConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(e => e.Notifications)
            .WithMany(e => e.Events)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("NotificationEvents"));
    }
}
```

There are cascade deletes on `Event` and `Notification` *from other tables*.

If I try to create the database, I get:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.NotificationEvents_dbo.Events_Event_Id' on table
>   'NotificationEvents' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Which is fair enough, given other cascades. Now my question is: **how to (or can I) specify no cascades on one or both sides *of this relationship only*?**

If I add (as suggested in another post):

```
class NotificationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Notification>
{
    public NotificationConfiguration()
    {
        HasOptional(e => e.Events).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

I get:

> The navigation property 'Events' declared on type
>   'Notification' has been configured with
>   conflicting multiplicities.